# Mostrar conteúdo no textboxfor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Gostaria de saber como faço para exibir o valor de uma propriedade dentro de um `textboxfor`. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
@model Calcular.Models.Conta

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Somar";
}

<h2>Somar</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Conta")) { 
<table>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Num1)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Num2)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Somar" value="Somar"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Subtrair" value="Subtrair"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Result)</td> 
</tr>
</table>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
   [HttpParamAction]
    public ActionResult Somar(Conta conta)
    {

        conta.Somar(conta.Num1, conta.Num2);
        return View("Somar", conta);
    }

    [HttpParamAction]
    [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Subtrair(Conta conta)
    {
        conta.Sub(conta.Num1, conta.Num2);
        return View("Somar", conta);
    }
```

Comment: Cadê o metodo Get da sua aplicação?

Comment: Eu queria passar dois valores digitados pelo o usuario, fazer a operação e retornar o valor para outro text box. Consegui fazer com ViewBag

Comment: você pode tentar usar o @Html.EditorFor() no lugar do @Html.TextBoxFor()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenho a impressão de que já respondi isso em outra pergunta, mas vamos lá.

Como o campo de soma (ou de subtração) não é gravado em banco, o ideal é fazer uma classe que seja muito semelhante à classe que representa seu *Model*, mas com alguns campos a mais, só que não mapeados em banco.

Então teríamos uma classe assim:

```
public class ContaViewModel
{
    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int Resultado { get; set; }

    public void Somar() 
    {
        Resultado = Num1 + Num2;
    }

    public void Sub() 
    {
        Resultado = Num1 - Num2;
    }
}
```

Este atributo [`[HttpParamAction]` você possivelmente tirou ele daqui](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/). Ele não é padrão no ASP.NET MVC. É usado para direcionar o `POST` para uma determinada `Action` do seu *Controller*.

Como retirei os parâmetros de `Somar` e `Sub` (porque eles não são necessários visto que as propriedades já existem dentro da classe), seu *Controller* ficaria assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpParamAction]
public ActionResult Somar(Conta conta)
{
    conta.Somar();
    return View("Somar", conta);
}

[HttpParamAction]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Subtrair(Conta conta)
{
    conta.Sub();
    return View("Somar", conta);
}
```

Para o `TextBoxFor`, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
@model Calcular.Models.Conta

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Somar";
}

<h2>Somar</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Conta")) { 

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Num1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Num2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Somar" value="Somar"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Subtrair" value="Subtrair"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Resultado)</td> 
        </tr>

    </table>

}
```